# Not able to fetch data from checkbox

Tags: php

So, i'm working on this real estate project, where users can add room details. Probblem is, when i check the checkbox for room one detail, i get information, but when i check the checkbox for another room (Please watch video), it does not show any information. Why?
Please watch this 20 sec video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-GDRsHV6Zs)

```
 <div class=" add-list-tags fl-wrap">
          <!-- Checkboxes -->
                                    <ul class="fl-wrap filter-tags no-list-style ds-tg">
                                        <?php foreach ($action->fetchData("facilities") as $key => $value) {

                                        ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="room_facilities[]">
                                                <label for="<?php echo $value['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                    </ul>
       <!-- Checkboxes end -->
  </div>
```

Comment: We can see how you're generating the checkboxes, but what code are you using to process them when the user has checked them? That seems to be the important part of your question. Provide us a [mre] of the issue so we can help you

Comment: Please also include a proper verbal explanation of the issue, instead of asking us to go watch videos elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your facilities's checboxes have the same name "room_facilities".

You'll need to differenciate the names (**edit: input names should probably based on the room the facilities are referring to**) to receive all of them.

```
 <div class=" add-list-tags fl-wrap">
    <!-- Checkboxes -->
        <ul class="fl-wrap filter-tags no-list-style ds-tg">
            <?php foreach ($action->fetchData("facilities") as $key => $value) {

            ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo '/*insert your room unique id here*/'; ?>_room_facilities[]">
                    <label for="<?php echo $value['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>

        </ul>
    <!-- Checkboxes end -->
  </div>
```

Comment: The name already was `room_facilities[]` already, which means PHP will create an array out of all the submitted values automatically. And the submitted value was a specific ID - so in theory, they should have had everything they needed, already. So it does not necessarily _need_ to be done this way, this all depends on the processing logic that comes after - but OP here completely failed to show us theirs.

Comment: @CBroe My guess is facilities have all the name/id despite the room they are in. But I should indeed correct my code since "room_facilities" should be identified with a room unique id and not a facility id. I'll edit it now, thanks for your input.